# Whats a text editor program for linux with ftp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Just a program i can code in like notepad++ for linux?
Thinking of installing linux and this is what i need most, if they don't have a program like notepad++ then i will not install it.

Comment: try to google it first

Comment: have you ever heard about vim (together with ssh)? :)

Comment: There's quite a few text editors for Linux: on the textual side, there's Vim, Emacs, Joe, Nano, and others. On the GUI side, there's (again) Vim and Emacs, but also gedit, Kate, and many others.

Comment: Text editors? Man that must be what Linux has the most.

Comment: I did google it, nothing came up. Atleast nothing like what i want, they say i have to install other crap.

Comment: I guess you should learn more about how Linux works before attempting to _program_ in Linux...If you love Notepad++ so much then you can use Wine, but yes it'll install _other crap_. That's how package management works.

Comment: @Cody: poor attitude mate

Answer (score 2):

Remote editing with any editor when using some Fuse based FTP-filesystem.

[CURLFFTPS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/)

```
urlftpfs -o user=username:password ftp.example.com /my/mount/point
```

---

Or you could use SSH and SSHFS if possible. http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

For the editor I would recommend Eclipse.

---

Or  should also checkout JetBrains' PHPStrom http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

---

GVim/Vim supports ftp & ssh/scp ([link1](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_remote_files_locally_via_SCP/RCP/FTP) [link2](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim))

Emacs is seemed to support them also ([link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp))

General format is: protocol:user@host#port:dir/file

---

**You can also use Gedit as Remote File Editor via FTP and SSH (Ubuntu)**

Using  Gedit as Remote File Editor via FTP and SSH (Ubuntu) ([link here](http://thecodecentral.com/2010/04/02/use-gedit-as-remote-file-editor-via-ftp-and-ssh-ubuntu))

Comment: Why this post was downvoted?

Comment: @hek2mgl i don`t know.. maybe it dont help them the way they want to be. no worries.

Comment: He asked for a text editor it's possible someone downvoted because you suggested IDE's.

Comment: The FUSE filesystem is a clever way to do it. +1

Comment: @kellax Note that `fuse` will be a general solution

Comment: i add also using Gedit as Remote File Editor via FTP and SSH (Ubuntu) what would you think of it? never been used it but from my research seems is gives some satisfaction to some ubuntu linux users.

Comment: But Eclipse/JetBrains are IDE's and Vim and Emacs are not really similar to Notepad++. Vim would be the obvious choice but if you don't want to learn how to use it then what remains are Notepad, Sublime, EText like editors.

Comment: 1. An IDE is *a text editor* (at least). 2. Vim is *the* text editor

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes but Vim is not Notepad like. Considering his question he is not familiar with Vim or he does not know how to use it or he does not like it. In any case he isn't looking for all the baggage of the IDE but simply for a text editor with ftp support similar to Notepad++. In this case Notepad++ over Wine is a choise where Sublime/E are the obvious choice.

Comment: `Notepad++ over Wine`?! as the preferred text editor on linux??!! HEHE never laughed that much before!! (really!) .. He could use gedit, kedit or whatever......... but not wine!!

Comment: @hek2mgl thumbs up.. ! why would he preferred use linux.. He should use windows instead..

Comment: I said `Notepad++ over Wine` is a choice I didn't say it was a OK I didn't even say it was an reasonable choice. However if user is familiar with `Notepad++` this is a choice for him. I did say that Sublime is the best choice for him and I stand by that. Because if you do not know Vim and have no desire to learn it and have no need for an IDE than Sublime is the best choice amongst text editors. If he migrated from Win to Linux and want's a editor similar to Notepad++ which by reading his question he does then Vim is not a choice and `Sublime` is. Unless he wants to learn how to use Vim first.

Comment: @kellax sometimes learning something new is a must  :).

Comment: Ye but that's not the point. I would suggest learning how to use Vim. However considering his question I would assume user does not wan't to take on Vim.

Comment: @kellax i think your the one voted me down.. lol :P

Comment: You don't need an expert for this any mentally challenged person who takes 1 look at Vim and Notepad++ will see they are not the same thing. If you read the users question you would see he is looking for something similar to Notepad++. It's the same as if I asked you: What's my alternative to raft to get across the river and you would tell me to learn how to fly a plane...

Comment: chill out.! both of you.. :D

Answer (score 0):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) has integrated FTP (and other protocols!) support with its bundled `netrw` plugin.

To use it, you can begin to edit a file as you would any other file, except you use a URL rather than a file name. For example:

```
$ vim ftp://www.example.com/file.txt
```

You can also give it a directory name rather than a file name and it will show you a directory listing.

For more information, see [its documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#pi_netrw.txt).

Comment: great answer! vim rulez! ;)

Comment: A little note if you do decide to try Vim is that Vim really is different from other editors. Vim is modal, whereas many other editors are modeless. If you try to forget or workaround Vim's modes, it won't ever work that well for you. You must embrace its modes.

Answer (score 0):

As **icktoofay** suggested Vim however if you don't have experience with Vim and wish to avoid learning how to use it then I would strongly suggest Sublime text.

If we are talking text editors I would add `Sublime Text` as the lead. It does not have FTP support included but has a superb `S/FTP` easy to install and use plugin.

**Sublime Text is like Notepad++ only better.**
[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Vim may be the best editor but it isn't similar to notepad++ at all.
For web development I would strongly recommend using **KDE's http://kate-editor.org/**
By taking advantage of KDE network stack, you'll have a (remote) filesystem browser, ftp editing, nice syntax hightlighting and symbol list for javascript, css and many other filetypes, column mode editing... It is nice clean and easy to use.
As a bonus, it is possible to run in vim emulation mode, so you can have both :)
I'm really astounded by how little attention has been given one of the best text editors